# Как в workbeanch при импорте в базу MySql поставить паузу

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Можно ли поставить на паузу импорт в MySql и как? Импортирую WorkbenchЕМ.

Comment: Экспорт - всегда "из". Если "в" - это импорт. Определитесь, что именно Вы делаете. PS. Думаю, нельзя - более того, думаю, что Вы первый, кому пришла в голову подобная идея, обычно все хотят, наоборот, побыстрее чтобы...

Comment: Ну конечно же Импорт :) Я тоже хочу побыстрее. Но место на диске подходит к концу. Хочу на паузу поставить, расширить диск и продолжить после перезагрузки компа.

Comment: Ого! ещё и перегрузиться! вот уж точно вряд ли... я понимаю - засуспендить процесс, да и то я лично не решился бы. Лучше срочно сноси с диска всё не очень нужное. Хоть куда.